# Fetching data through ajax using jQuery

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have two pages in different server.

Through ajax I would like to include some data: here is an example: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/TSJGU/)

The link is working through browser.

```
jQuery(window).ready(function() {
    getPageWithAjax("http://www.betcatcher.com/index.php?page=valuebets&nr_row=6");
    function getPageWithAjax(page)
    {        
        //alert(page)
        ajaxRequest = $.ajax(
                    {
                        url: page, 
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(msg){ajaxResponse(msg)},
                        error: function(msg){ajaxResponse('Error loading data.'+msg.status)} 
                    });    
    }
    function ajaxResponse(msg)
    {
        $("#live_bet_ajax_content").html(msg);
    }

});
```

But I'm getting error when I'm trying to get data.

Comment: use firefox + firebug, and using the net tab you should be able to see what's wrong there.

Comment: Yes, I'm also using firebug, but I couldn't figure out what the problem is.

Comment: is the requested url in the same domain that you send the request?

Comment: "I'm getting error". could you actually POST that error here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume, that you call script from different domain. You should use JSONP which supports cross-domain calls. Read [this article](http://remysharp.com/2007/10/08/what-is-jsonp/) how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

looks to me like a Same-Origin Policy problem. For new browsers you could enable Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) http://enable-cors.org/ for old browser you probably need to build a serverside proxy which rewrites the requests.