# The function .ajax cross domain and mysql don't work correctly

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a problem with this code. I have a page that executes a jQuery function, and the query in the url that gets requested is used in a function to execute 2 `INSERT` queries but I only have one.

**JavaScript code**

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "url on different domain",
  crossDomain:true,
  cache: false,
  success: function(html){
       alert(html);
  },
error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                    alert(xhr.status);
                    alert(thrownError);
                },    
  statusCode: {
    404: function() {
      alert('page not found');
    }
  }
});
```

The code of url requested is:

```
<?php 
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers:X-Requested-With,Host,User-Agent,Accept,Accept-Language,Accept-Encoding,Accept-Charset,Keep-Alive,Connection,Referer,Origin'); 
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET");

  $db = mysql_connect('localhost','usr','pwd') or die("Database error");   
  mysql_select_db('db', $db); 

  $dati_arr=explode("|", $termine); 
  $dati_insert['email']=$dati_arr[0]; 
  $dati_insert['pwd']=$dati_arr[1]; 
  $dati_insert['nome']=$dati_arr[2]; 
  $dati_insert['cognome']=$dati_arr[3]; 
  $dati_insert['tipo']=$dati_arr[4]; 

  $query="INSERT INTO ".$table." VALUES ('','".implode("','", $values)."')";   
  if(mysql_query($query)){$exec="ok";}
?>
```

But in my database I have 2 records.

Comment: Read my comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8375055/fetching-data-through-ajax-using-jquery/8375124#8375124

Comment: @Roberto - I've done my best to make this a bit more readable, however I'm finding it hard to understand what the problem really is. The cross-domain request security will just stop the `response` being accessible by the browser, it won't stop the request url actually being requested.

Comment: Well, can you  show an example of you insert? I really don't think ajax is the real problem here.

Comment: If you keep an eye on the network tab of your browser console, is it being called twice?

Comment: @khael 

This is the php code the .ajax find in php page

$db = mysql_connect('localhost','usr','pwd') or die("Database error"); 
mysql_select_db('db', $db);

$dati_arr=explode("|", $termine);
 
$dati_insert['email']=$dati_arr[0];
$dati_insert['pwd']=$dati_arr[1];
$dati_insert['nome']=$dati_arr[2];
$dati_insert['cognome']=$dati_arr[3];
$dati_insert['tipo']=$dati_arr[4];

$query="INSERT INTO ".$table." VALUES ('','".implode("','", $values)."')";
if(mysql_query($query)){$exec="ok";}

Comment: This is somewhat familiar. Could you add some quick logging directly after your header(...) calls and then die()? How many lines of text do you have in this log file: $f = fopen('log.txt', 'w'); fwrite($f, time() . '-' . microtime() . ": Called\n"); fclose($f); die();

Answer (score 0):

I suspect all your code is working perfectly as *written*.

It's far more likely that your user is either hitting the button twice or for some other reason your javascript call is being called twice. Either way you should have protection in place to prevent multiple button presses from being submitted at once.

You can do this either by several means e.g.:

i) having a flag in javascript for 'requestBeingProcessed', check that it's false before doing the ajax call, then set it to true until the request is processed.

ii) Set the button that is doing this to 'display: none' while the request is being processed - and replace the button with a little spinning icon.

iii) Have a unique identifier on the page which gets passed in with the ajax call - and only allow that unique identifier to be used once to submit that button press.

I'd suggest putting in an 'alert("debugging info")' just before your ajax call so you can investigate whether the event is always being triggered twice or whether it's just the user, and then put the double-click protection in.

cheers
Dan